# Flex DropDownList ItemRenderer probably a bug

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, drop-down-menu, itemrenderer

I am trying to make a simple change on look of Flex 4.5 Spark DropDownLis trough extending it's item renderer, anyway even a just shiny new item renderer bring me as result a items which labels is blanks.
If i remove the renderer everything is fine, but with it - the items is blank white.

```
<s:DropDownList id="cbX" x="140" y="281" width="276" itemRenderer="comboItemRenderer" labelField="@text">
    <mx:XMLListCollection>
        <fx:XMLList>
            <node text="1" />
            <node text="2" />
            <node text="3" />
        </fx:XMLList>
    </mx:XMLListCollection>
</s:DropDownList>
```

item renderer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:Label text="{data}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Is it a bug, or i am doing it wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <s:Label text="{label}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The data for the renderer is still the data. But if you use `labelField` you rely on List's label calculation routine. So just display it.

Comment: For the god sake, where is written all of thoose things. I feel like i am comming from another galaxy :( thank you very much. it do the trick, but i really don't understand how to know about theese relations on data...

Comment: To tell the truth `labelField` is the way to not to use custom item renderer to display some field of your data provider item. In your case using `label` in renderer is the same as using `data.@text`. So if you renderer is the same as standard one (as in your case) just use standard default renderer. If you're going to use some advanced item renderer you can remove `labelField` from List and move all the logic inside renderer using `data`.